# Stop folium from scaling raster values

Tags: python, folium

Folium seems to do some scaling on raster values which messes with categorical rasters. See example below using a raster with values of 3,4, and 8 only. 8's show up as red instead of maroon. I'd like to stop folium from scaling the data so I can use categorical colourmaps.

```
import folium
import numpy as np
import branca.colormap as cm
from PIL import ImageColor


raster_data = np.random.randint(low=3, high=9, size=(10, 10))
raster_data[np.where(np.logical_and(raster_data>4, raster_data<8))]=4


custom_colormap = [(0, 255, 255, 255.0),
 (0, 0, 255, 255.0),
 (0, 255, 0, 255.0),
 (255, 128, 0, 255.0),
 (255, 0, 0, 255.0),
 (128, 0, 0, 255.0)]

cmap = branca.colormap.StepColormap(custom_colormap,
vmin=2.5, vmax=8.5, index=[2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5]))

cmap_func = lambda x: ImageColor.getcolor(cmap(x), 'RGBA') if ~np.isnan(x) else (0,0,0,0)



m=folium.Map(location=(-31.05, 151.15), zoom_start=12)


image_overlay = folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(
    image=raster_data,
    bounds=[[-31.0, 151.1], [-31.1, 151.2]],  
    zindex=1,
    colormap=cmap_func,
).add_to(m)

m.add_child(cmap)
m
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Would the notes on the image overlay example on the [official sample page](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/user_guide/raster_layers/image_overlay.html) be helpful to you? 
*Note that you need to provide a colormap of the form lambda x: (R,G,B,A) where R,G,B,A are floats between 0 and 1.*

Comment: There's 4 options. RGB or RGBA between 0 and 1 or between 0 and 255